# Push view not pushing UIViewController from single view based application

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I choose the project template as "Single View" .I am  trying to push a detail view(UIViewController) on the button click.Button action is firing properly and executing the code [self navigatingController] push......My code is As:

```
MapDetailViewController *mapDetailViewController = [[MapDetailViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapDetailViewController animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"self.navigation is as %@",self.navigationController);
```

self.navigationController is null.So i tried to alloc init a local variable of type Navigation Controller and also the variable was able to be non-null(some hex value), still i was unable to push the mapDetailView.
what i am thinking is that i have choosen the wrong template(view based).Should i choose the Navigation-based(Master-detail).Well the below auto generated code is of application delegate:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Should some changes be made here for navigation controller?
Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't even have a navigation controller to do the pushing.  Change your code to this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but it should be pointed out that this code belongs where the initial view controller is created, usually in the app delegate.

Comment: @Mark great it solved my problem however now on my rootviewController a navigation bar is displaying(obviously).i am able to use isHidden:YES, to make it hidden.Is there not any other way so that i could be able to push my detail view controller without making Navigation controller as rootViewController.

Comment: Caleb: Fixed. Maddy: Generally a navigation bar is used when popping and pushing views.  I am not sure about pushing/popping without one, but you should keep in mind that by using one you will automatically have a back button generated for the user, and this is a design pattern that is prevalent throughout iOS.

Comment: @mark i hide the navigation bar in the masetr uiviewcontrol in viewWillAppear.Now as i pushed the detailview no navigation bar in detailView.Why? i have hidden only in the master UIViewController.So i explicitly force detailView Controller's navigation bar isHidden:NO.Now what i noticed is that when i tap back button in detail view controller and popping to back whola!! the top navigation bar in detail view becomimg black(while transiting to masterViewController) or say my view from detailViewController shifted below and above is the blank space.

Comment: I don't believe there is a clean way to have the navigation bar hide and show the way you want it to.  I would suggest just leaving it there at all times.  It often comes in handy in the master view for putting UIBarButtonItems on it.